# node.js how to access its html file

Tags: node.js

I'm working on an app that uses a node package for some of its content and css. How do I access the templates? The folder structure for the package is `packageName/src/packageName/templates/basket/partials/index.hbs` The contents of that file is only html.

I want to use the contents of index.hbs in one of my app's hbs files. In the route handler for the page I have set up a variable to get that data and pass to the view, but I dont know how to expose the contents of the index.hbs file to the route handler. Do I read it in the fs package? or is there another way to access it?

I'm inexperienced with node so let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using require in the route handler worked nicely.

route_handler.js

```
const html = require('packageName/src/packageName/templates/basket/partials/index.hbs');

module.exports = {
  res.render('pageView', {
    html: html
  });
};
```

pageView.hbs

```
{{{ html }}}
```